# how to write to a file with a fixed template in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, toml

I have a fixed template to be written which is pretty long as,

```
REQUEST DETAILS
RITM :: RITM1234
STASK :: TASK1234
EMAIL :: abc@abc.com
USER :: JOHN JOY

CONTENT DETAILS
TASK STATE :: OPEN
RAISED ON :: 12-JAN-2021
CHANGES :: REMOVE LOG
```

something like this, which would be 100 lines.

Do we have any way to store it as template or store it in files like ".toml" or similar files and write to values(right side of ::) in python?

Comment: You should try `string.Template`. template string can be stored in a simple text file and can be written into file format of our choice after substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the inputs as placeholders using `$` and save it as txt file. Then use [Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

```
from string import Template
t = Template(open('template.txt', 'r'))
t.substitute(params_dict)
```

Sample,

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> t = Template('Hey, $name!')
>>> t.substitute(name='Bob')
'Hey, Bob!'
```

Answer (score 2):

For template creation I use jinja :

```
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Template

# Function creating from template files.
def write_file_from_template(template_path, output_name, template_variables, output_directory):
    template_read = open(template_path).read()
    template = Template(template_read)
    rendered = template.render(template_variables)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_name)
    output_file = open(output_path, 'w+')
    output_file.write(rendered)
    output_file.close()
    print('Created file at  %s' % output_path)
    return output_path



journal_output = write_file_from_template(
        template_path=template_path,
        output_name=output_name,
        template_variables={'file_output':file_output, 
            'step_size':step_size, 
            'time_steps':time_steps},
        output_directory=output_directory)
```

With  a file named `file.extension.TEMPLATE`:

```
# This is a new file :
{{ file_output }}
# The step size is :
{{ step_size }}
# The time steps are :
{{ time_steps }}
```

You may need to modify it a little bit, but the major things are there.