# Pandas read_sql_query with parameters for a string with no quotes

Tags: pandas, postgresql, parameters

I have want to insert a string of identifiers into a piece of sql code using

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.connection,params=sql_parameter)
```

my parameter dictionary looks like this

```
sql_parameter = {'itemids':itemids_str}
```

where itemids_str is a string like

```
282940499, 276686324, 2665846, 46875436, 530272885, 2590230, 557021480, 282937154, 46259344
```

The SQL code looks like

```
SELECT 
xxx, 
yyy, 
zzz
FROM tablexyz
where some_column_name in ( %(itemids)s )
```

My current code gets my the parameter inserted with its quotes

```
where some_column_name in ( '282940499, 276686324, 2665846, 46875436, 530272885, 2590230, 557021480, 282937154, 46259344' )
```

How can I prevent the string being inserted including the ', these are not part of my string, but I assume they come from the parameter type string when using %s

Comment: Well, `itemids_str` is a string or no? What you want to do instead is have one placeholder for each `itemid`. There are many SO questions and answers about how to do this. You can use `*` to build up a list of placeholders from the length of `itemids_str`. You would also then need to do `itemids_str.split(',')` to get that into a list.

Comment: Yes it is a string, I construct that string from the individual itemids and thought I can pass it as a single argument

Comment: If you prefer to do that -- which, please note, could be a potential security flaw -- you would need to use Python string formatting on your query before sending it to `pd.read_sql_query()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a provision in params to send a list of numeric values for one condition. I always add such condition directly to the query

```
item_ids = [str(item_id) for item_id in item_ids]

where_str = ','.join(item_ids)

query = f"""SELECT 
    xxx, 
    yyy, 
    zzz
    FROM tablexyz
    where some_column_name in ({where_str})"""
```

Comment: thanks, would this also work if the query would be outside the code in a separate .sql file ?

Comment: You can use to string.Template to load the query from file. `$` is used for the placeholders. Do check the documentation, this should work even if the query is in a file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832412/14292065